# Is it possible to compare two .java files methods and fields in all cases?

Tags: java, performance, reflection, compare

I am currently taking a project management class and the professor gave this assignment to compare two .java files methods and fields in all cases programmatically. **I don't think it's actually possible to do** but maybe I am wrong!

The assignment spec is as following (its extremely ambiguous I know)

```
In this assignment, you are required to write a comparison tool for two 
versions of a Java source file.
Your program takes as input two .java files representing those two versions
and reports the following atomic changes:

1. AM: Add a new method
2. DM: Delete a method
3. CM: Change the body of a method (note: you need to handle the case where a method is
relocated within the body of its class)
4. AF: Add a field
5. DF: Delete a field
6. CFI: Change the definition of an instance field initializer (including (i) adding an initialization to a
field, (ii) deleting an initialization of a field, (iii) making changes to the initialized value of a field,
and (iv) making changes to a field modifier, e.g., private to public)
```

So that's what I am working with and my approach was to use reflection as it allows you to do everything but detect differences in the method body.

I had considered the idea that you could create a parser but that seemed ridiculous, especially for a 3 credit undergrad class in project management. Tools like BeyondCompare don't list what methods or fields changed, just lines that are different so don't meet the requirements.

I turned in this assignment and pretty much the entire class failed it with the reason as "our code would not work for java files with external dependencies that are not given or with java files in different projects" - which is completely correct but also I'm thinking, impossible to do.

**I am trying to nail down a concrete answer as to why this is not actually possible to do or learn something new about why this is possible so any insight would be great.**

Comment: definitely not impossible. Take a look at https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser . Looks like you could just parse the 2 java files and look for changes.

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What you got wrong here is that you have started to examine the .class files (using reflection).** Some of the information listed above is not even available at that stage (generics, in-lined functions). What you need to do is parsing the .java files as text. That is the only way to actually solve the problem. A very high-level solution could be writing a program that:

- reads the files
- constructs a specific object for each .java file containing all the informations that needs to be compared (name of the functions, name of the instance variables, etc)
- compares the constructed objects (example: addedFunctions = functionsFromA.removeAll(functionsFromB)) to provide the requested results

*Note: if this is an assignment, you should not be using solutions provided by anybody else, you need to do it on your own. Likely you will not get a single point if you use a library written by somebody else.*

Comment: Thanks Gergely, I already turned in the assignment and everything, I was just wondering for curiosity at this point. Wouldn't the parser have to be extremely extremely robust to handle things like generic and in-lined functions though? I had considered parsing everything but came up with so many exceptions to account for it didn't make sense. This was a regular homework assignment, we get a new one every two weeks. Maybe I am overestimating the amount of work, but creating a parser to do that seems like an incredibly daunting task. Is is not that bad really?

Comment: Compared to using reflection, it is certainly easy. :) But really: the list of items you need to discover is pretty basic and you should be able to solve in 4-6 hours if you have sufficient experience. The truly exceptional cases (different type of inner classes, static initializer blocks, wildcard imports) are not part of your assignment, those would be the tricky things to track.